# Tf-idf calculation using gensim

Tags: python, tf-idf, gensim

I have one tf-idf example from an ISI paper. I’m trying to validate my code by this example. But I get different result from my code.I don’t know what the reason is!

Term-document matrix from paper:

```
acceptance     [ 0 1 0 1 1 0
information      0 1 0 1 0 0
media            1 0 1 0 0 2
model            0 0 1 1 0 0
selection        1 0 1 0 0 0 
technology       0 1 0 1 1 0]
```

Tf-idf matrix from paper:

```
acceptance     [ 0   0.4   0   0.3   0.7  0
information      0   0.7   0   0.5   0    0
media            0.3  0   0.2   0    0    1
model            0    0   0.6   0.5  0    0
selection        0.9  0   0.6   0    0    0 
technology       0   0.4   0   0.3   0.7  0]
```

My tf-idf matrix:

```
acceptance     [ 0   0.4   0   0.3   0.7  0
information      0   0.7   0   0.5   0    0
media            0.5  0   0.4   0    0    1
model            0    0   0.6   0.5  0    0
selection        0.8  0   0.6   0    0    0 
technology       0   0.4   0   0.3   0.7  0]
```

My code:

```
tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus)   
corpus_tfidf=tfidf[corpus]
```

I’ve tried another code like this:

```
transformer = TfidfTransformer()
tfidf=transformer.fit_transform(counts).toarray() ##counts is term-document matrix
```

But I didn’t get appropriate answer

Comment: What is your corpus?

Comment: @Mahmood Kohansal -- dictionary: ' {u'media': 0, u'technolog': 3, u'accept': 4, u'inform': 2, u'model': 5, u'select': 1} ' and corpus: ' [[(0, 1), (1, 1)], [(2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1)], [(0, 1), (1, 1), (5, 1)], [(2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1)], [(3, 1), (4, 1)], [(0, 2)]] '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of this difference between results as you mentioned is that there are many methods to calculate TF-IDF in papers. if you read [Wikipedia TF-IDF page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) it mentioned that TF-IDF is calculated as

> tfidf(t,d,D) = tf(t,d) . idf(t,D)

and both of tf(t,d) and idf(t,D) can be calculated with different functions that will change last result of TF_IDF value. Actually functions are different for their usage in different applications.

[Gensim TF-IDF Model](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/tfidfmodel.html) can calculate any function for tf(t,d) and idf(t,D) as it mentioned in it's documentation.

> Compute tf-idf by multiplying a local component (term frequency) with
>   a global component (inverse document frequency), and normalizing the
>   resulting documents to unit length. Formula for unnormalized weight of
>   term i in document j in a corpus of D documents:
>
> `weight_{i,j} = frequency_{i,j} * log_2(D / document_freq_{i})`
>
> or, more generally:
>
> `weight_{i,j} = wlocal(frequency_{i,j}) * wglobal(document_freq_{i}, D)`
>
> so you can plug in your own custom wlocal and wglobal functions.
>
> Default for wlocal is identity (other options: math.sqrt, math.log1p,
>   ...) and default for wglobal is log_2(total_docs / doc_freq), giving
>   the formula above.

Now if you want to reach exactly the paper result, you must know what functions it used for calculating TF-IDF matrix.

Also there is a good example in [Gensim google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gensim/ml_gBOZRxYU) that shows how you can use custom function for calculating TF-IDF.

Comment: Do you got this answer helpful?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had guessed before that it was because  of algorithm but I tried 3 or 4 different algorithms  and I  couldn’t get the mentioned answer...The thing that is strange for me is that using any algorithm for tf-idf shouldnt result in completely different final answer of text clustering! But each time I change tf-idf algorithm I get different clusters!! (I use SVD to extract factors)

Comment: I think dependency of answers to tf-idf method is clear as I said in answer. Anyway you can accept the answer if you get it correct.

Comment: you're right. but I think TF-IDF weighting is just an auxiliary method to improve weights so it shouldn't affect the final answer