# I want to preprocessing text with WIDF (Weighted Inverse Ducument Frequency) alghorithm using python code

Tags: python, text-processing

I've searched for formulas and code in various sources but I haven't found

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ask a specific question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: please checks the  links:- [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516295/tf-idf-calculation-using-gensim) and [link2](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/introduction-to-natural-language-processing-in-python/simple-topic-identification?ex=11)